# Removing (almost) duplicate solutions

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I recently made a 24 game solver (it lives [here](https://oliverni.com/24/)), but some of the solutions I get are basically the same:

[image: Almost duplicate expressions]

I need a way to remove these duplicate expressions. Here is what counts as "the same":

- Commutative Property — `a+b = b+a`, `a*b = b*a`
- Associative Property — `(a+b)+c = a+(b+c) = (a+c)+b`, `(a*b)*c = a*(b*c) = (a*c)*b`
- Double Negatives — `a-(b-c) = a-b+c`, `a/(b/c) = a/b*c`

Can anyone come up with an algorithm to do it or an example?

Comment: for your first problem: If you have multiple numbers "concatenated" by a `+ or *` sort them. then you can compare for equal parts/eqpressions. To the second problem: if your bracket only contains `+ or *` and the ascending op is the same, extend the bracket `(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)` -> `(a+b+c) = (a+b+c)`, then you can continue with the first sorting, ... You may also want to implement an algo that removes unnecessary brackets, third one is trickier, there you have to explicitely define what combinations of operators a double negative are and search for them.

Comment: You can convert your strings to a Tree format, and calculate values at different depths. If the values at different depths for one expression matches the other expression's values at the same depths, you know knock off one of them. The Commutative and probably Double negative property

Comment: But before all of that, you must use Shunting Yard Algorithm to knock off all the expressions with just different number or different placement of brackets. The Associative Property.

Comment: @AliYousuf Ahh, thanks.